# How to use gsub() to change an entire string when containing some character

Tags: r, gsub

```
df <- data.frame(
  sample = c("A", "B", "C", "D"), 
  class = c("A31", "A3", "A31,C", "A3,B"),
  value = c(5,1,6,8) )
```

I would like to in this df replace all the strings containing `A3` (e.g. `A3,B`) to just `A3` without affecting `A31` and `A31,C`?

I’ve tried `df$class <- gsub("A3.*", "A3", df$class)`, but this also changes `A31` and `A31,C`.

Comment: `gsub("A3,.*", "A3", df$class)`  try this if all cases follow this pattern

Comment: Don't have R to test with, but how about `A3,.*`?

Comment: You want to replace A31,C... without affecting A31,C. Can you revise your question to make it clearer?

Answer (score 1):

We could capture the upper case letter (`[A-Z]`) followed by a digit as a group (`(...)`) that precedes one or more digits (`\\d+`) till the end (`$`) of the string and replace with the backreference (`\\1`) of the captured group

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
df <- df %>%
    mutate(class = str_replace(class, "^([A-Z]\\d)\\d+$", "\\1"))
```

-output

```
df
  sample class value
1      A    A3     5
2      B    A3     1
3      C A31,C     6
4      D  A3,B     8
```